# What dictionary formats are supported by StarDict?

Tags: dictionary

What dictionary formats are supported by StarDict?

I cannot find any info on their website.

Answer (score 0):

Per wikipedia...

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/StarDict

...it offers a link to a list of dictionaries in the FreeDict format that you can convert to StarDict format.